# Python: Palidrome (string index out of range)

Tags: python

I tried to write a method called is_palidrome_v3(s) to compare the word's first and last letter, then 2nd and last 2nd letter, until the pair is not the same, and finally check if the index is >= len(s)//2

```
def is_palidrome_v3(s):
    ''' (str) -> bool

    Return True if and only if s is a palidrome.

    >>> is_palidrome_v3('noon')
    True
    >>> is_palidrome_v3('racecar')
    True
    >>> is_palidrome_v3('dented')
    False
    '''

    i = 0
    while i <= len(s) // 2 and s[i] == s[len(s) - i]:
        i = i + 1

    return i >= len(s)//2
```

But when i run it:

```
is_palidrome_v3('noon')
```

there's an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module> is_palidrome_v3('noon') 
File "C:\Users\James\Google-h0925473\Learning Programming\Python\Python Fundamental (Coursera)\is_palidrome_v1.py", line 67, in is_palidrome_v3 while i <= len(s) // 2 and s[i] == s[len(s) - i]: 
IndexError: string index out of range
```

can some one tell me what's wrong inside?

Thx!!!

Comment: Hey, @AswinMurugesh // is a Python operator, **not a comment!**

Comment: @KobiK Check the edit history. The first edit after OP posted was AswinMurugesh changing // to #.

Comment: You should understand that a[len(a)-1] is the same as saying a[-1] too. Both will return the last letter in string a.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your code,

the line:

```
while i<=len(s)//2 and s[i] == s[len(s)-i]
```

is the problem. At the first iteration, the conditions are:

```
while 0<=len(s)//2 and s[0] == s[len(s)]
```

And there is no way for an index `len(s)` to exist in a string. Thus the error. Change it to:

```
while i<len(s)//2 and s[0] == s[len(s)-i-1]:
```

This will save the problem

Why make such a fuss?

Checkout this cool way:

```
if s == s[::-1]:
    return True
return False
```

s[::-1] the first `:` says we have to iterate from the start. The second `:` says iterate till the end. So, `::` normally means we have to iterate throughout the string. the -1 at the end says the string has to be interpreted from the right ( reverse). So we check if the string is equal to its reverse

Comment: You should explain why `s[::-1]` reverses the string. The OP could be trying to learn Python.

Comment: `return s == s[::-1]`

Comment: Better, but you still do not explain how extended slices work.

Comment: @SteveP. Is it ok now?

Comment: yes, i'm learning Python. And, i don't understand the :: syntax. Can you explain why? THX!!!

Comment: @user2988464: Can you understand it now?

Comment: @user2988464 `s[a:b:c]` means go from `[a,b)` stepping by `c`, ie `s[::2]` means take every other element from the list.  `s[-1]` means the last character of `s`.  `s[::-1]` means take the entire string, but going from the end to the beginning.

Comment: i got it!!
Cool Answer!! Thank you guys!!

Comment: Note that the "cool" solution creates a (completely unnecessary) copy of the whole string in memory.

Comment: Much better answer now.

Answer (score 2):

On the first iteration, i = 0. So

```
s[len(s) - i]
```

becomes:

```
s[len(s)]
```

which is not accepted as the last character in the string is at index len(s) - 1.

You should change this to:

```
s[len(s) - i - 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an off by one error. If i == len(s), then s[i] is an IndexError, because indexes count from 0.

So with < instead of <= in the loop it should work:

```
def is_palidrome_v3(s):
    i = 0
    while i < len(s) 2 and s[i] == s[-i]:
        i = i + 1

    return i >= len(s)  #2
```

Note that I changed s[len(s) - i] to s[-i], if you use negative indices then it counts from the end, so that's an easy shorthand, and it also fixed a second bug: s[len(s) - i] is also an IndexError, this time when i is 0.

I think that you're trying to learn Python step by step (hence the v3) so I'm not going to bother giving various easier ways to do it :-)